# Collapse type definition in tsx file in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When I create a type definition in a typescript file (.ts) I am not given the option to collapse the definition in VS Code.  For example:

```
export type Test = {
    someValue: string,
    someOtherValue: string,
    yetAnotherValue: string
};
```

I don't get the option in the left margin to collapse this definition.  Is there a setting that I'm missing to allow this?  Does an extension like prettier have the ability to add this?  I have been unable to find a solution so my current workaround is to put a region around it.

Answer (score 3):

1. `Ctrl + Shift + P` Preferences: *Open settings(JSON)*
2. Add

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation"
},
"[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation"
},
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation"
},
"[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation"
}
```

3. That's All